# (SQL Server Trigger) The multi-part identifier could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I tried to create Trigger on table TAKES and I received 4 similar errors:

> The multi-part identifier "Inserted.course_id" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "Inserted.sec" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "Inserted.semester" could not be bound.
>
> The multi-part identifier "Inserted.year" could not be bound.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_capacity ON takes FOR INSERT
AS
        DECLARE @max_capacity      INT;
        DECLARE @current_capacity  INT; 
        DECLARE @course_id  VARCHAR; 
        DECLARE @sec_id  VARCHAR; 
        DECLARE @semester  VARCHAR; 
        DECLARE @year_  INT; 
BEGIN
        SET @course_id = inserted.course_id;
        SET @sec_id = inserted.sec;
        SET @semester = inserted.semester;
        SET @year_ = inserted.year;
        SET @max_capacity = dbo.get_max_capacity(@course_id,
                                                @sec_id,
                                                @semester,
                                                @year_);

        SET @current_capacity = dbo.get_current_capacity(@course_id,
                                                          @sec_id,
                                                          @semester,
                                                          @year_);

        IF ( @max_capacity > @current_capacity ) BEGIN
                print 'Insert successfully';
        END
        ELSE BEGIN
                print 'Max capacity ' + isnull(@max_capacity, '');
                print 'Current capacity ' + isnull(@current_capacity, '');
                print 'The classroom is full! Choose the others';
        END 
END
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). [Bad Habits to Kick : Abusing triggers](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-abusing-triggers)

Comment: The error is also telling you the problem, what is `inserted.semester`? What is the object `inserted`, there is no `FROM`. But, as the articles above tell you, you have multiple other fatal flaws here.

Comment: I ***hope*** you aren't still assuming a trigger effects one row, and a `varchar` is always one character long in your solution.

Comment: If you want to use inserted you have to `SELECT` from it... and as Larnu says, it could have 0-N records, you appear to assume only one. I recommend reading [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: @TungNg. You don't have the reference of inserted. So, these columns mentioned by the error exists and cannot identify the origin of these columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this

```
SELECT @course_id = course_id, 
       @sec_id = sec, 
       @semester = semester,
       @year_ = year
  FROM INSERTED
```

then set your other values.

Answer (score 1):

**This trigger has a number of major flaws:**

- [Not taking into account multiple (or zero) rows being inserted](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/05/the-silent-bug-i-find-in-most-triggers/)
- `PRINT` does not prevent the transaction from occurring, you need `THROW`. Note that you should not manually `ROLLBACK` in a trigger, throwing an exception will do  that for you
- Using scalar functions, which are very bad for performance. (I can't fix this as I don't know what they do)
- If @max_capacity is *equal* to @current_capacity then it will also fail, which I assume is not supposed to happen
- Using `varchar` without a length is wrong, it defaults to `varchar(1)` in some cases

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER check_capacity ON takes FOR INSERT
AS

DECLARE @max_capacity      INT;
DECLARE @current_capacity  INT; 

IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE dbo.get_max_capacity(i.course_id, i.sec_id, i.semester, i.year) <
          dbo.get_current_capacity(i.course_id, i.sec_id, i.semester, i.year)
))
    THROW 70000, N'The classroom is full! Choose the others', 0;

GO
```

If you want the exact numbers to show in the error message, you can do this, but it will only show the results from the first non-conforming row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_capacity ON takes FOR INSERT
AS

DECLARE @max_capacity      INT;
DECLARE @current_capacity  INT; 

SELECT TOP (1)
  @max_capacity = v.max_capacity,
  @current_capacity = v.current_capacity
FROM inserted i
CROSS APPLY (VALUES
     (dbo.get_max_capacity(i.course_id, i.sec_id, i.semester, i.year),
      dbo.get_current_capacity(i.course_id, i.sec_id, i.semester, i.year))
) v(max_capacity, current_capacity)
WHERE v.max_capacity < v.current_capacity;

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @msg nvarchar(150) = CONCAT('Max capacity ', @max_capacity, '
Current capacity ', @current_capacity, '
The classroom is full! Choose the others');
    THROW 70000, @msg, 0;
END;

GO
```